# GPU duty_cycle metric is being reported as a weird value like `5334m`?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a hpa defined as:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: prototype-gpu-scaler
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: prototype
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
    - type: External
      external:
        metric:
          name: kubernetes.io|container|accelerator|duty_cycle
        target:
          type: AverageValue
          averageValue: 50
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 50
```

However when I sometimes look at the stats I'm seeing strange values for `kubernetes.io|container|accelerator|duty_cycle`, a value such as `5334m`?

For example with the object described:

```
kubectl describe hpa prototype-gpu-scaler
Warning: autoscaling/v2beta2 HorizontalPodAutoscaler is deprecated in v1.23+, unavailable in v1.26+; use autoscaling/v2 HorizontalPodAutoscaler
Name:                                                                       prototype-gpu-scaler
Namespace:                                                                  default
Labels:                                                                     <none>
Annotations:                                                                <none>
CreationTimestamp:                                                          Tue, 14 Mar 2023 16:51:21 +0000
Reference:                                                                  Deployment/prototype
Metrics:                                                                    ( current / target )
  "kubernetes.io|container|accelerator|duty_cycle" (target average value):  5334m / 50
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):                       23% (279m) / 50%
Min replicas:                                                               3
Max replicas:                                                               8
Deployment pods:                                                            3 current / 3 desired
Conditions:
  Type            Status  Reason               Message
  ----            ------  ------               -------
  AbleToScale     True    ScaleDownStabilized  recent recommendations were higher than current one, applying the highest recent recommendation
  ScalingActive   True    ValidMetricFound     the HPA was able to successfully calculate a replica count from cpu resource utilization (percentage of request)
  ScalingLimited  False   DesiredWithinRange   the desired count is within the acceptable range
Events:           <none>
```

What is the meaning of this value? When referring to CPU usage `1000m` is equal to 1 CPU core, but on the other hand this value is meant to be a 0 - 100 value (according to https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/gpus#monitoring)?

> Duty Cycle (container/accelerator/duty_cycle): Percentage of time over the past sample period (10 seconds) during which the accelerator was actively processing. Between 1 and 100.

Comment: Seems pretty clear.  5,334ms out of the last 10s would be 53% duty cycle.

Comment: It does not seem clear to me at all, percentage over time should still be  value of 0-100%. If I said a car was in use 50% of the time during a year, surely this number would not be compounded for each second. But you might be correct here - at least the number seems plausible.

Comment: It says it's the time over the last 10 seconds.  It gave you the raw value (5330ms) and the percentage (50%).

Comment: In general, duty cycle indicates the 'on' or 'off' time in percent, ranging from 0% to 100% of period for repetitive pulse train, here they are considering a constant time period of 10s for taking the samples. So as per your metrics the pulse on duration is 5334ms(milli seconds) converting to seconds 5.334 s now your duty cycle percentage is 5.334/10 *100 = 53.34% just an extension to what @TimRoberts said. hope this will help you..

Comment: **[This](https://www.fluke.com/en-in/learn/blog/electrical/what-is-duty-cycle#:~:text=Duty%20cycle%20is%20the%20ratio,and%20OFF%20the%20other%2040%25) is the source from which the duty cycle definition taken**

Comment: How is this not confusing?? `m` is meant to be for 'milicores' - that is the only place I've ever seen it being used. And now you're saying it's for miliseconds (in which case surely it would be ms not m). Either case the duty cycle should surely return a % and not a ms. 

Regarding that 50% value - that is the target value. I appreciate the input though.